# Why is cyclopropane planar?

Tags: organic-chemistry, computational-chemistry, stability

What would cyclopropane look like if it weren't planar?

How and why does non-planar cyclopropane have higher torsional strain than planar cyclopropane? can you please show me visually via image that non-planar cyclopropane has higher torisional strain and maybe more angle strain than planar cyclopropane?

On the otherhand, why and how is cyclobutane bulged or puckering, a.k.a non-planar?

Comment: Considering that three points define a plane, geometrically, it's not really possible for cyclopropane to be non-planar...

Answer (score 12):

> Why is cyclopropane planar?

This is like asking why $\ce{HCl}$ is linear–just as two points define a line, three points define a plane. There isn't any way to orient the three methylene groups in space that they aren't coplanar.

$\hspace{8cm}$[image: plane]

Torsional strain in cyclopropane is also significant for this reason (the molecule has a $\mathrm{C_3}$ axis through the center of the ring, meaning every hydrogen is overlapping). Any reduction in torsional strain, however, decreases the already weak carbon-carbon $\ce{sp^3}$ orbital overlap. Though the $\ce{C-C-C}$ bond angles are $60º$, the orbitals are still oriented roughly $109.5º$ from one another, resulting in very weak and highly strained [banana bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent_bond).

$\hspace{8cm}$[image: strain]

> Why is cyclobutane nonplanar?

Cyclobutane has one additional methylene, and can reduce its torsional strain by orienting one methylene out of the plane of the other three.

$\hspace{7.3cm}$[image: cyclobutane]

This is in part possible due to the much greater carbon-carbon $\ce{sp^3}$ orbital overlap.

Comment: Due to symmetry, the carbon in cyclopropane is not $sp^3$ but $sp^2$ hybridized.

Answer (score 2):

If cyclopropane did pucker then a new plane would exist. This is because any set of three points (a.k.a three carbons) is coplanar. Cyclobutane puckering can occur and make a difference as a set of four points/carbons is not necessarily coplanar.